# Multiple Implementation of DbContext Register in asp.net DI system

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to register multiple DbContext implementations in aspnet core DI

so I registered DbContext as bellow

```
services.AddScoped(c => new CoreDbContext(c.GetService<DbContextOptions<CoreDbContext>>()));
services.AddScoped(c => new TnADbContext(c.GetService<DbContextOptions<TnADbContext>>()));
services.AddScoped<Func<DbContextType, IDbContext>>(provider => key =>
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case DbContextType.Core:
            return provider.GetService<CoreDbContext>();
        case DbContextType.TnA:
            return provider.GetService<TnADbContext>();
        case DbContextType.Payroll:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(key), key, null);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(key), key, null);
    }
});
```

so from repositories, I'm trying to request instance like below

```
private readonly IDbContext _context;
public Repository(Func<DbContextType, IDbContext> resolver)
{
    _context = resolver(DbContextType.TnA);
}
```

But when I run the application it throws an exception as below

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
>   the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Web.Areas.TestController
>   Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Web.Areas.TestController':
>   Unable to resolve service for type 'Data.IDbContext' while attempting
>   to activate 'Service.InterfaceService'.)

Basically almost all services and controller complaining about the same issue. 
So what was the missing part?

***UPDATE***

Actually I made some changes on registering DB context now it work

```
services.AddScoped<Func<DbContextType, IDbContext>>(provider => key =>
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case DbContextType.Core:
            return new CoreDbContext(provider.GetService<DbContextOptions<CoreDbContext>>());
        case DbContextType.TnA:
            return new TnADbContext(provider.GetService<DbContextOptions<TnADbContext>>());
        case DbContextType.Payroll:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(key), key, null);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(key), key, null);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you missed registering the `IDbContext` with the IoC container.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I figured out the issue. The issue was I have one service still directly inject IDbContext. When i replace the injection with `Func<DbContextType, IDbContext> resolver` and resolve using `var context = resolver(DbContextType.TnA);` It worked perfectly Thanks

Comment: Great that you got it working :) Could you add an answer so other people with a similar problem can see this as a resolved question?

Comment: Yes i will add  updated section as answer

Answer (score 1):

So I came up with solution registering Dbconfigs as below

```
services.AddScoped<Func<DbContextType, IDbContext>>(provider => key =>
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case DbContextType.Core:
            return new CoreDbContext(provider.GetService<DbContextOptions<CoreDbContext>>());
        case DbContextType.TnA:
            return new TnADbContext(provider.GetService<DbContextOptions<TnADbContext>>());
        case DbContextType.Payroll:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(key), key, null);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(key), key, null);
    }
});
```

And Make sure IDbContext not to inject any services instead you can try as below

```
private readonly IDbContext _context;

public InterfaceService(Func<DbContextType, IDbContext> resolver)
{
    _context = resolver(DbContextType.TnA);
}
```

DbContext type would be an enum that contains the type of DB context that I need to inject